# Liferay DXP (7.0) refuses to reindex

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-dxp

I'm working on a portal where I'm responsible for the searching. I'm using for example JournalArticleIndexerPostProcessor, to add custom fields in the index...

After reindexing a lot of data (full - reindex), I noticed my code was being stale / stuck, and I've kill -9'd the tomcat service. (Locally off course). Not a good plan, since I've rebooted tomcat, cleaned work / temp / state etc, I'm not able to reindex the portal anymore.

I press on the button: Reindex all... Nothing happens.. I press Reindex JournalArticles.. I see something is happening.. But in ElasticSearch, nothing seems to happen.

Advice? I've got this once before, and I just reverted my local setup. But that's a lot of work.. Is there something stale in the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your server didn't stop correctly, you can have some background tasks in a incorrect state.

Stop your server and review following tables:

```
SELECT * FROM BackgroundTask
SELECT * FROM Lock_
```

If you correctly shutdown your server:

- It should be no Lock in the system
- All background tasks should be in a non-running state: *failed=2, sucessfull=3 or canceled=5* (full status list, see: [BackgroundTaskConstants.java](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/85dbdc57a0a5e6ef7da657761af00d92c74962ee/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/backgroundtask/BackgroundTaskConstants.java#L51-L61) )

This answer was copied from Liferay forum, see: https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/87596606